# How to avoid immediate execution of periodic request in Workmanager

Tags: android

I have a requirement where job must happen every hour. The catch here is job must not happen immediately as soon as we enqueueUniquePeriodicWork. It must wait for an hour and then trigger the work.

Answer (score 1):

It might be late but you can use `PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder#setInitialDelay`:

```
PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
        UpdateWorker::class.java,
        1,
        TimeUnit.DAYS,
        10,
        TimeUnit.MINUTES
    ).setInitialDelay(1L, TimeUnit.HOURS).build()
```

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkRequest.Builder#setInitialDelay(java.time.Duration)) states:

> Blockquote